# How to swap out a sprite in Unity2D based on a Dictionary entry?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm very new to Unity and programming in C# altogether, so apologies if this is a little elementary;

Basically I want to change a sprite in my game for 10 seconds, and then change back to the original sprite. I have stored this sprite in a dictionary entry, as well as the sprites that I wish to change to in a List. I create these dictionary entries with a loop that filters in the correct name for the sprites and other entry values based on our position in the loop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PaddleAbilities : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Dictionary<string, Ability> AbilitiesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Ability>();

    [Header("GUI Sprites")]
    public List<Sprite> abilitySprites;

    [Header("Ability Costs")]
    public int Q_Cost;
    public int W_Cost;
    public int E_Cost;
    public int R_Cost;

    [Header("Ability Cooldowns")]
    public float Q_Cooldown;
    public float W_Cooldown;
    public float E_Cooldown;
    public float R_Cooldown;

    //ability ready timers
    public bool Q_Ready = true;
    public bool W_Ready = true;
    public bool E_Ready = true;
    public bool R_Ready = true;

    //access Scripts
    [Header("Other")]
    public GameManager gameManager;
    public Paddle paddle;
    public int Score;
    public string thisPlayer;
    private Vector2 Position;

    void Awake()
    {
        //get our Game Objects
        gameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        paddle = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Paddle>();

        //Get resource position
        Position = this.gameObject.transform.position;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //which player is this script assigned to?
        if (Position.x < 0)
        {
            thisPlayer = "P1";
            Score = gameManager.scoreValueP1;
        }
        else if (Position.x > 0)
        {
            thisPlayer = "P2";
            Score = gameManager.scoreValueP2;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int Cost = 0;
            switch (i)
            {   case 1: 
                    Cost = Q_Cost; 
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    Cost = W_Cost; 
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    Cost = E_Cost; 
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    Cost = R_Cost; 
                    break; 
            }

            float Cooldown = 0;
            switch (i)
            {   case 1: 
                    Cooldown = Q_Cooldown; 
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    Cooldown = W_Cooldown; 
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    Cooldown = E_Cooldown; 
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    Cooldown = R_Cooldown; 
                    break; 
            }

            if(thisPlayer == "P1")
            {
                string P1Name = "Ability" + i + "_P1";
                AbilitiesDictionary.Add(P1Name, new Ability(P1Name, GameObject.Find(P1Name).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite, Cost, Cooldown));
            }
            else if (thisPlayer == "P2")
            {
                string P2Name = "Ability" + i + "_P2";
                AbilitiesDictionary.Add(P2Name, new Ability(P2Name, GameObject.Find(P2Name).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite, Cost, Cooldown));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Ability
    {
        public string SpriteName { get; set; }
        public Sprite AbilitySprite { get; set; }
        public int AbilityCost { get; set; }
        public float AbilityCooldown { get; set; }

        public Ability(string spriteName, Sprite abilitySprite, int abilityCost, float abilityCooldown)
        {
            this.SpriteName = spriteName;
            this.AbilitySprite = abilitySprite;
            this.AbilityCost = abilityCost;
            this.AbilityCooldown = abilityCooldown;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        AbilitiesRead();

        if (thisPlayer == "P1")
        {
            Score = gameManager.scoreValueP1;
        }
        else if (thisPlayer == "P2")
        {
            Score = gameManager.scoreValueP2;
        }
    }

    //Key press check gets called in update
    public void AbilitiesRead()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && Q_Ready && Score >= AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilityCost)
        {
            Debug.Log(thisPlayer + " attempted to spawn a ball.");
            StartCoroutine(ServeBall());
        }
    }

    //ENUMERATORS v
    private IEnumerator SkillDuration(float WaitTime)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Skill is active. Waiting for skill to deactivate.");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
    }

    private IEnumerator ServeBall()
    {
        gameManager.serveTowards = paddle.Opponent; //make sure we serve at our opponent when this ability is called
        gameManager.SpawnBall(1); //spawn a Ball (the ball will use this paddle.Opponent to determine which direction to go in.)

        Q_Ready = false; //this ability is now on cooldown.

        Score -= AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilityCost; //deduct our Ability Cost
        AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilitySprite = abilitySprites[1]; //swap out Q_sprite for this player to the greyscale version "Q_Ability_onCooldown.psd"
        yield return StartCoroutine(SkillDuration(AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilityCooldown)); //WaitForSeconds for the amount of time we want to cooldown for.
        AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilitySprite = abilitySprites[0]; //swap out Q_sprite for this player to the color version "Q_Ability.psd"

        Q_Ready = true; //this ability is now ready to be used again.
    }
}
```

Here are my sprites in the Hierarchy. I was able to confirm that my dictionary entry DOES find the sprites, but when I set that entry equal to the sprite in the list that I want to change to, nothing happens on the Unity side of things.

[Ability Sprites in Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uocch.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 AbilitiesDictionary.Add(P1Name, new Ability(P1Name, GameObject.Find(P1Name).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite, Cost, Cooldown));
```

Instead of referencing the sprite itself, you should reference the SpriteRenderer and exchange the sprite of the SpriteRenderer like this:

In your AbilityClass reference the Renderer:

```
 public class Ability
{
    public string SpriteName { get; set; }
    public SpriteRenderer AbilitySprite { get; set; }
    public int AbilityCost { get; set; }
    public float AbilityCooldown { get; set; }

    public Ability(string spriteName, Sprite abilitySprite, int abilityCost, float abilityCooldown)
    {
        this.SpriteName = spriteName;
        this.AbilitySprite = abilitySprite;
        this.AbilityCost = abilityCost;
        this.AbilityCooldown = abilityCooldown;
    }
}
```

Add the Renderer to your Class

```
if(thisPlayer == "P1")
        {
            string P1Name = "Ability" + i + "_P1";
            AbilitiesDictionary.Add(P1Name, new Ability(P1Name, GameObject.Find(P1Name).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>(), Cost, Cooldown));
        }
```

Exchange the sprite:

```
AbilitiesDictionary["Ability1_" + thisPlayer].AbilitySprite.sprite = abilitySprites[1];
```

The code is untested so no guaratee there are no spelling errors ;)